# MBProgressHUD use private api setLabelText

Tags: ios, xcode6, iphone-privateapi

My app use MBProgressHUD with 0.9.1 with pod. After submit the app, I got email from apple saying my app use private api "setLabelText". I did some search and
find out the MBProgressHUD has reference of setLableText. But I cant find the reference in source code. Any suggestion to pass apple's review?

Here is the result of nm on the build in Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Pods/MBProgressHUD.framework:

nm MBProgressHUD  |grep setLabelText
0000bed0 t -[MBProgressHUD setLabelText:]
000000000000b6e0 t -[MBProgressHUD setLabelText:]

Comment: It's a setter so the property is named `labelText`  [Line 104](https://github.com/jdg/MBProgressHUD/blob/master/MBProgressHUD.m)

Comment: You may [check this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12575477/the-same-situation-second-time-be-rejected-because-of-used-mbprogresshud)

Comment: I have successfully submitted apps with MBProgressHUD

Answer (score 0):

It sounds strange that Apple would have a private property on UIView called `labelText` but if they did reject your app becuase of this, the proper Open Source, way of handling this problem would be:

1. Fork https://github.com/jdg/MBProgressHUD to your own github account.
2. On your local version of MBProgressHUD change all references to the  property `labelText`to something else (maybe just call it `text`).
3. Create a branch with your changes and push to your fork.
4. Change your Pod file so it points to your branch instead of the original MBProgressHUD.
5. Open a pullrequest to the owner of MBProgressHUD repo, and explain why you did change property name.
6. If your changes is merged to master branch, you can point your Pod back to the original again.
7. Be happy to have contributed back to the Open Source community! :-)